# Пропускается работа for

Tags: python, sqlite3

**Код:**

```py
    elif callback.data == 'menu':
        chat_user_id = callback.message.from_user.id

        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT game_nickname FROM users WHERE user_id = ("%s")' % chat_user_id)
        users = cur.fetchall()
        conn.commit()

        for user_name in users:
            print('1')
        
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
```

Код пропускает `for`, для проверки написал `print('1')` - не выводит, не понимаю в чем проблема. Если вывести `print('1')` за пределы `for`, то вывод будет также с пропуском.

Comment: может, у вас в users пусто?

Comment: да, я проверил, там пусто, но тогда вопрос почему пусто появился

Comment: Пусто, потому что условие `user_id = ("%s")` не выполняется. PS: никогда не используйте конкатенацию строк для составления SQL-запросов! Используйте параметризацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в `WHERE user_id = ("%s")`. Не было данных о айди пользователей в бд.